# android app is crashing and showing this error. I have changed the dependency versions multiple times also but nothing is working

Tags: android, firebase, exception

2023-09-23 12:16:25.889 22438-22438/com.example.firebaseauth E/le.firebaseauth: Attempt to load writable dex file: /data/data/com.example.firebaseauth/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex
2023-09-23 12:16:28.948 22438-22438/com.example.firebaseauth E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.firebaseauth, PID: 22438
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firebaseauth/com.example.firebaseauth.login}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.firebaseauth. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.firebaseauth. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:179)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.1.2:1)
at com.example.firebaseauth.login.onCreate(login.java:47)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

tried all the versions of dependencies also.

Comment: What you are implementing here?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase released version 11.5 to solve this crash